# MXNet AdamW optimizer

Tags: deep-learning, mxnet, mxnet-gluon

Adam optimizer has flaws when used with weight decay. In 2018, AdamW optimizer has been proposed.

Is there any standard way to implement AdamW in MXNet framework (python implementation)? There is `mxnet.optimizer.Adam` class, but no `mxnet.optimizer.AdamW` one (checked in `mxnet-cu102==1.6.0`, `mxnet==1.5.0` package versions).

*P.S. I asked this questions [on MXNet forum](https://discuss.mxnet.io/t/implementing-adamw-in-mxnet/6074) and [on datascience.stackexchange.com](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/73460/mxnet-adamw-optimizer), but to no avail.*

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: There isn't a standard way to use AdamW in Gluon yet, but there is some existing work in that direction that would make that relatively easy to add.

Longer answer:

- People have been asking for this feature - a lot :)  See: https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/issues/9182
- Gluon-NLP has a working version of AdamW - possibly slightly different from the one in the original paper: https://github.com/eric-haibin-lin/gluon-nlp/blob/df63e2c2a4d6b998289c25a38ffec8f4ff647ff4/src/gluonnlp/optimizer/bert_adam.py
- The `adamw_update()` operator was added with this pull request: https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/pull/13728  This is first released in MXNet 1.6.0.
- Unfortunately, it looks like there isn't a way to use this with `gluon.Trainer` directly right now, without copying/modifying the `BERTAdam` code (or writing something similar from scratch).  That would be a *very nice* thing to add to Gluon.

Please let me know if you get this working, as I'd love to be able to use that as well.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to write something within some spare time.